# Update DialogFragment message runtime

Tags: android

How can i update `DialogFragment` message at the runtime?
Please see my codes :

```
CustomDialog dialog = CustomDialog.getInstance(generator);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "backup_progress");
while(progressBarStatus)
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) dialog.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.custom_progress_dialog_message);
    messageTextView.setText(message);
    getDialog().findViewById(R.id.custom_progress_dialog_message).invalidate();
}
```

And after show i want to change dialog message but it's throwing exception, i think my way is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Did you just try:

```
setTitle("new text")
```

I think this is what you want to achieve. If not I am sorry and I misunderstood.